# Want to make entire Tabhost disappear or invisible onclick of a particular tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

Say,I am having 2 `tabs` in my `TabActivity` and on clicking on one of the `tabs`,I am into my `Activity` called `FirstTab`.When I am here in this particular class, I do not want my `TabHost` to be visible.

That is whenever I click on the tab I want my `TabHost` to disappear.

How can I do that?

#### Code snippet:

```
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");  
firstTabSpec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
firstTabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class)); 
tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
```

#### EDIT:My Xml:

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
 android:background="@drawable/bar_green"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TabWidget>
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I am having a simple `FirstTab Activity` which is displaying down under the `TabHost` on clicking my `tab` which I want to convert it into the class without containing `TabHost`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try set visibility of TabHost to "View.GONE"

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
                public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                    if (tabId=="firstTabId")
                        getTabHost().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

But are you sure you want do exactly this? How user can return to second tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use TabHost then here is the other way that you can achieve it.I dont know whether it is useful to you or not.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SubActivity.class));

        }
    });
}
```

}

SubActivity.java

```
public class SubActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
    {
        super.onCreate(instance);
        setContentView(R.layout.sub);
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/buttonpanel" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Your stuff goes here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

sub.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Subactivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

buttonpanel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Tab1" android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Tab2" android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you can modify layouts and activity as per your need.

Comment: Good idea @Hitendra.Even I had thought the same, but for some reason I want to make use of `TabHost`.Anyways thanks a lot and one up:)